# Hide Error on Select Value (Select2)

Tags: jquery

I have this SELECT2 box:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Status <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>

            <select id="status_id" name="status_id" class="select" required="required" data-placeholder="Select">

                <option></option>
                <option value="Google">Google</option>
                <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
                <option value="Mailing">Mailing</option>
             </select>
     </div>

 </div>
```

If I submit form without selection, warning appear below field, like: Please select a value.

***I'm tryng to hide warning message when select any value***

Here my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var form = $('#contact_add').validate({

    });

    $('#status_id').on('select2:select', function (e) {
        form.valid();

    });

});
```

Comment: Up? ...........